# PHP - Google Recaptcha proxy setup

Tags: php, symfony, security, proxy, recaptcha

I am using PHP wrapper library for Google Recaptcha.
https://packagist.org/packages/google/recaptcha

I need to set up a proxy, but as I investigate, this library does not have support for proxy configuration.

Is there anyone who has the opportunity to successfully configure a proxy configuration for Google Recaptcha?

This is properly working code on the server without proxy

```
    /**
     * RecaptchaService constructor.
     *
     * @param ReCaptcha $recaptcha
     */
    public function __construct(ReCaptcha $recaptcha)
    {
        $this->recaptcha = $recaptcha;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $data
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validateCaptcha(array $data): bool
    {
        $response = $this->recaptcha->verify($data['gRecaptchaResponse'], $data['clientIp']);

        return $response->isSuccess() || \PHP_SAPI === 'cli';
    }
```

I guess that proxy should be configured before or within the `verify` method call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fork of Google ReCaptcha library with proxy support

https://github.com/toskadv/recaptcha

```
$curl = new ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\CurlPost(null, null, [
    CURLOPT_PROXY => 'http://127.0.0.1:9050/',
    CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE => CURLPROXY_SOCKS5
]);
$recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($secret, $curl);
$resp = $recaptcha->verify($gRecaptchaResponse, $remoteIp);
if ($resp->isSuccess()) {
    // verified!
} else {
    $errors = $resp->getErrorCodes();
}
```